# Cluster migration visualization

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, data-visualization

I have asked a very similar question at the Latex forum [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200121/visualizing-cluster-data?noredirect=1#comment465103_200121), but in order to address the part of my question where I ask if there is a better way of visualizing the data I have, I wanted to cross post it here. As i can get a bit more technical:

I can choose the number of clusters, but I think it wont exceed 20. The mappings create a 100-dimensional vector for each word, and clusters are generated from them with k-means. Just to reiterate, the difficulty for me lies in the way in which migrating data, which is put into one cluster for the first mapping and into another cluster in the second one can be shown in a clear and precise way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks from the sketch that you made on the latex forum site that you would like to do some form of parallel coordinate plot. Check the ggparallel package in R, and accompanying papers. This package will allow you to have categorical variables, which I think you have given that are looking at words. Rearrange the variables in different ways to determine how the clusters differ on the different features.

It is going to be messy - there is no way around that with 20 clusters and 100 variables. You could do some filtering of the variables, but selecting the top X for separating the clusters, or for separating cluster 1 from the other  clusters. You could also plot each cluster separately, but using the same axis limits as the entire data set.

(There is also a parallel coordinate plot function in the GGally package, but this is for real-valued variables.}

Comment: I looked into parallel plots, and it seems to be what I need to do. Thank you!